# populate an array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have 2 schemas

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        id_film: {
            type: Number,
            unique: true,
            require: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        recommendation: [{
            type: Number,
            ref: 'Films'
        }]
    }, { timestamps: true }, { _id: false }
);
export const Recommendation = mongoose.model("Recommendations", schema);




const schema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name:{
      type: String,
   }
    id: {
      type: Number,
      ref: 'Recommendations'
    },
}
export const Films = mongoose.model("Films", schema);
```

the recommendation contains a list id of model Films, and I want to show all id film

i try it

```
Recommendation.findOne({ id_film: req.params.id }).populate('recommendation').exec(function (err, film) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            res.json(film);
        });
```

but it's not working, it just shows the list id not id and name

Comment: Not sure, but maybe in `Films`, `id` is not configured as `unique`. That can be an issue during population.

Comment: Oh thank you, i know it